# Need help, where to start

Tags: ros, mobile, keyboard-teleop, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm beginner in ROS, and don't know where to start my task. I'm studied beginner tutorials and want to build robot. My robot is tricycle with two drive wheels and one slave respectively. Drivers are control by two servo, and servo must controled by ROS via modbus protocol. For a start I want moving it (forward, backward, left, right) from keyboard. And dont know what nodes me need.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60219/need-help,-where-to-start./) by [Kirill_Sokolov](https://answers.ros.org/users/4634/kirill_sokolov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-04-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Kirill,

I suggest you write a "driver" node for your robot. It should subscribe to a topic called "cmd_vel" (although you can rename it if you want) of type [geometry_msgs/Twist](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html). The Twist messages tell you how fast the robot should move forward (msg.linear.x) and how fast it should turn (msg.angular.z); you can ignore all other fields of the message. You can have a look at the [turtlebot_node](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_create/blob/master/create_node/nodes/turtlebot_node.py) to get an idea how to calculate individual speeds for the two motors from this info. Then you "only" have to send this speed to the servos. :-)

As a publisher, you can use the keyboard teleop node from the [turtlebot_teleop](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_teleop) package (don't be confused by the name turtlebot, it works with all robots).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kirill_Sokolov](https://answers.ros.org/users/4634/kirill_sokolov/) on 2013-04-09**:
O good, it is what I need, thanks Martin=). So at node "driver" i have only implementation of the protocol modbus. And so turtlebot_teleop publishing messages of type Twist?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-04-10**:
Exactly, that's how it works. Glad I could help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The industrial stack has some modbus programs but they are for a gripper. Perhaps you can modify them for your servo drivers. But that is not easy for a beginner.

[The Robotiq package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robotiq/Tutorials/Control%20of%20an%20S-Model%20Gripper%20using%20the%20Modbus%20TCP%20Protocol)

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-04-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kirill_Sokolov](https://answers.ros.org/users/4634/kirill_sokolov/) on 2013-04-09**:
I think I do not need to use this stack, because it is realy dificult for me now=)